# Do HTML Comments Increase the Load time of a webpage?

Tags: html, optimization, comments

If I add a lot of comments to my site, will it increase the load time for a user that doesn't have a fast internet connection?

Comment: Yes, you send more bytes from server to client but is not significant on load terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments do not have a negative impact on the loading time (the browser ignore it), only on the downloading time but is not significant.

If you have problems with load times the are other factor you can improve:

- Optimizing images
- Bundle and minify javascript code in an unique file
- Expiration headers (Specify cache in the browser)
- Script loading in bottom of the html before body clousure tag
- Avoid redirections
- Enable compression
- It is also important to analyze the server load with the active site (cpu, memory, databases)

> A good tool for analyze and optimization web pages is [google
>   pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Comment: np @TaylorRose enabling compression and optimizing images (with compression too and size) it represents a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Not impact . but more important is optimization of js, CSS and Images files, It can be make slower your site if it are not optimized.